# How can I figure out the values of $x$ and $y$ where $xy = (x+3)(y-3) = 2550$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find values of $x$ and $y$ where $$xy = (x+3)(y-3) = 2550$$
I really can't figure it out without using guess and check methods, which are worthless.

If it was ($x+3)(x-3)$ then that would be fine, but it isn't. The numbers could be 2 and 1275 for all I know.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

To begin with, notice that
\begin{align*}
xy = (x+3)(y-3) = xy - 3x + 3y - 9 \Longleftrightarrow 0 = -x + y - 3 \Longleftrightarrow x = y -3
\end{align*}

Thus you have the following system of equations to solve
\begin{cases}
xy = 2550\\\\
x = y - 3
\end{cases}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: so $x$ and $y$ are irrational

Comment: I think I can take it from here. Thanks for your help and explanation.
$x=49$ and $y=52$ (ish)

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do to simplify this.

We have $xy=(x+3)(y-3)=2250$.

Expand this to give $xy=xy+3x-3y-9=2250$.

Now subtract $xy$ from "both" sides, ignoring the $2250$ for now, which gives us $3x-9=3y=2250$. Factor out a $3$ on the LHS to give $3(x-3)=3(y)$. Divide both sides by $3$ to have $x-3=y$.

Now, plug $y$ into the original equation to give $2250=(x+3)(x-6)$, which is just $2250=x^2-3x-18$, which you can easily solve for $x$.

Can you finish the rest?

Answer (score 0):

Another path to what user1337 came up with is this, using a mental computation trick that’s useful in its own right.

The trick is the handy formula $$ab=\left({a+b\over2}\right)^2-\left({a-b\over2}\right)^2.$$ As an aside, this comes from the high-school algebra formula $c^2-d^2=(c+d)(c-d)$ and is how a mental calculator might calculate $29\cdot21$; it’s the (average of $29$ and $21$) squared minus half-the-difference squared, or $25^2-4^2$, which is $625-16-609$. (You can solve a lot of multiplication problems with this if you just memorize perfect squares.)

Notice that the average of $x$ and $y$ equals the average of $x+3$ and $y-3$. If the products $xy$ and $(x+3)(y-3)$ are equal and the averages of each pair of factors (the square of which is the first term of the formula) are equal, the second term in the formula must also be the same for each pair of factors. That is, $x$ and $y$ must differ by the same amount as $x+3$ and $y-3$, so their half-difference squared is the same for each pair. In other words, $x-y\over2$ and ${(x+3)-(y-3)\over2}={x-y+6\over2}$ must have equal squares. The only time two different numbers can have equal squares is when one is the negative of the other. So adding $6$ to $x-y$ must turn $x-y$ into its negative. That only happens if $x-y=-3$

The calculation trick also helps finish up the problem. (Since the OP said they could take it from the earlier answers, I hope I’m not giving too much away now.) Now that we know $x$ and $y$ differ by $3$, we know that their product is $1.5^2=2.25$ less than the square of their average. So the square of the average of $x$ and $y$ is $2550+2.25$, and $x$ and $y$ are, respectively, $3\over2$ less than and $3\over2$ greater than their average, $\sqrt{2552.25}={\sqrt{10209}\over2}$.